# How to disable logs from k8s_cluster on Stackdriver Logging?

Tags: logging, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

We have a Google Coud Platform project where we use a cluster to deploy our apps, we have noticed on our billing this month that Stackdriver Logging increased too much so we started to create exclusions.

We excluded logs from `resource.type="container"` without any problem,
**but we are not able to do it from** `resource.type="k8s_cluster"`

*filter to create our desired exclusion:*

```
resource.type="k8s_cluster"
protoPayload.serviceName="k8s.io"
protoPayload.resourceName="app.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/applications/prometheus-1"
```

A curious thing is that Stackdriver Monitoring doesn't detect any data *(0B ingested)* from there, neither from our gcp-project (https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/usage?project=xxxx) unless we filter it using the logs viewer, then we can see the logs.

Grafana is able to detect the data with Stackdriver Datasource, you can see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ielfr.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filter for `resource.type="k8s_cluster"` contains Audit Logs for [System Events](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/#system-event) that are always enabled, hence, they won't be excluded from Stackdriver Logging unlike `resource.type="container"` that only has container stdout and stderr logging.

Furthermore, you can determine which logs belong to the Audit Logs stream by adding the '@type' condition to your Stackdriver filter:

```
resource.type="k8s_cluster"
protoPayload.serviceName="k8s.io"
protoPayload.resourceName="app.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/applications/prometheus-1"
protoPayload."@type"="type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"
```

Finally, Grafana is able to display these log-based metrics since they're exported into it via Datasource instead of going into Stackdriver.